# Deny access to linked server to access my data

Tags: sql-server

I added MsSQL to MSSQL linked server, I would like to know whether the linded server can able to access my data without my knowledge?

Comment: What do you mean "without your knowledge"? Do you mean can that linked server query back to the server you've linked from? No. Connections aren't "two-way". If you want Server B to also be able to access Server A, you've need to create a linked server on Server B to Server A.

Comment: I am server A, I am linking Server B in my Server A.  Now what I suspect is whether server B can able to access my databases?  Because I dont want server B to connect my server.  I dont find any clarity on this in microsoft documentation about linked server.

Comment: As I stated, the set up isn't bidirectional.